# How to view network resources used by a thread in Linux

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to check the network resources used by a thread but unable to figure out how. lsof only allows us to give the pid. I checked under /proc/**pid**/task/**thread**/ but could not find anything related to network connections.

Does anyone know how to view this information ?

Comment: Need more detail. What do you mean by network resources?

Comment: Network connections. Similar to what lsof would display for a process.